# Inner Join with multiple row uses

Tags: mysql

I need to select 2 rows from the members table to get name and id, and I need to get all rows from message table. Here is what I have so far any tips or help is appreciated
EDIT
Tables

[image: MEMBERS] 
[image: msgs]

```
 SELECT member_messages.message_to, 
       member_messages.message_from, 
       member_messages.message_time, 
       member_messages.message_body,
       members.display_name,members.id 
FROM members
INNER JOIN member_messages 
   ON member_messages.message_to = members.id  AS 'to'
INNER JOIN member_messages 
   ON member_messages.message_from = members.id AS 'from'
WHERE member_messages.message_to = '$userId'
```

Comment: Can you actually use reserved keywords as column names in mySql?

Comment: To which column name do you comment?

Comment: In other words, I don't know if you can have a column name called `from` unless you put it in quotes..  Then again, I don't know mySql very well..

Comment: ahh, will change that then as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your joins are almost correct, but you need to refer to the table aliases `to` and `from` which you assigned in the `JOIN`s in the `SELECT` list, rather than referring to `members` directly.  Since both `TO` and `FROM` are [MySQL reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) you must backquote both of them.

```
SELECT member_messages.message_to, 
       member_messages.message_from, 
       member_messages.message_time, 
       member_messages.message_body,
       /* Select cols from both aliases of members, with column aliases */
       `to.display_name AS to_name,
       `to`.id AS to_id ,
       `from`.display_name AS from_name,
       `from`.id AS from_id 
/* First reference to members as `to` */
FROM members AS `to`
INNER JOIN member_messages 
   ON member_messages.message_to = `to`.id
/* Second reference to members as `from` */
INNER JOIN members AS `from` 
   ON member_messages.message_from = `from`.id
WHERE member_messages.message_to = '$userId'
```

Comment: There must be something that I am missing hmm

Comment: @kabuto178 So what are you getting? Error? No rows? What?

Comment: no rows and if this helps , "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to`.id AS to_id , `from'.display_name AS from_name, `from`.id AS' at line 5"

Comment: @kabuto178 Just a missing closing quote on the `\`from\`.display_name` line.

Comment: XD, that was not seen. Thanks very much, accepted. appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you put the db structure here. Assuming that your table 'member_messages' contains all the messages you want to read, then you need to join this one twice with your 'members' table to retrieve name of the 'from' and 'to' members.

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    message.message_time, message.message_body,
    member_to.id, member_to.display_name,
    member_from.id, member_from.display_name
FROM   
    member_messages AS message
JOIN   
    members AS member_to ON members.id = member_messages.message_to 
JOIN   
    members AS member_from ON members.id = members_messages.message_from
```

If some of the words are reserved in your db system, change them.